# List of all lemma in a book to be listed at the end of Book/Document

Tags: automation, lemma

I am writing a book in latex in memoir class. The book is divided chapter wise and contains definition, lemma, theorems. Can the process of collecting all lemma at the end of the book be automated as it is added in each chapter. This can be very handy for students for going through and recalling all results.

Comment: It could be done, but not by me. Roughly speaking typeset lemmas where they are specified and also write the lemma code to an external file to be read in and processed later. Somewhat like the code for `memoir`'s endnotes. Or perhaps just use `endnotes`.

Comment: If you provided an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}` that included a lemma I might try and provide an `endnote` answer, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: It helped thanks - endnotes.